# Nativescript CLI Emulator View not refreshing. ns run

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript

I recently started working on a NativeScript project. But when running the app using ns run android, it doesn't apply any changes. When i make changes it says compiling changes and doesn't show any errors, but the app doesn't restart or refresh. Even if I manually restart the app I can't see any changes. The only way to see changes is to use ns run android --clean which takes way to long.

Answer (score 0):

- ns clean
- ns run android --bundle

This should do the trick